# Display required product options on every page in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

We can create custom options in opencart and link those options with product according to our need. i want to display the required product options on every pages i.e category, search result rather than only on product detail page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show required options in category by editing these two files:

**File:**

```
catalog\controller\product\category.php
```

**Find:**

```
$data['products'][] = array(
```

**Replace with:**

```
$options = array();

foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($result['product_id']) as $option) {
    if($option['required']){
        $product_option_value_data = array();

        foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
            if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                    'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                    'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                    'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                    'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                    'price'                   => $price,
                    'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                );
            }
        }

        $options[] = array(
            'product_option_id'    => $option['product_option_id'],
            'product_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
            'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
            'name'                 => $option['name'],
            'type'                 => $option['type'],
            'value'                => $option['value'],
            'required'             => $option['required']
        );
    }
}

$data['products'][] = array(
    'options' => $options,
```

**File:**

```
catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.twig
```

**Somewhere inside for loop, or find:**

```
<div class="button-group">
```

**Add before it:**

```
{% if product.options %}
<hr>
<h3>{{ text_option }}</h3>
{% for option in product.options %}
{% if option.type == 'select' %}
<div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <select name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}]" id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}" class="form-control">
    <option value="">{{ text_select }}</option>
    {% for option_value in option.product_option_value %}
    <option value="{{ option_value.product_option_value_id }}">{{ option_value.name }}
    {% if option_value.price %}
    ({{ option_value.price_prefix }}{{ option_value.price }})
    {% endif %} </option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if option.type == 'radio' %}
<div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
  <label class="control-label">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <div id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}"> {% for option_value in option.product_option_value %}
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}]" value="{{ option_value.product_option_value_id }}" />
        {% if option_value.image %} <img src="{{ option_value.image }}" alt="{{ option_value.name }} {% if option_value.price %} {{ option_value.price_prefix }} {{ option_value.price }} {% endif %}" class="img-thumbnail" /> {% endif %}                  
        {{ option_value.name }}
        {% if option_value.price %}
        ({{ option_value.price_prefix }}{{ option_value.price }})
        {% endif %} </label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %} </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if option.type == 'checkbox' %}
<div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
  <label class="control-label">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <div id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}"> {% for option_value in option.product_option_value %}
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}][]" value="{{ option_value.product_option_value_id }}" />
        {% if option_value.image %} <img src="{{ option_value.image }}" alt="{{ option_value.name }} {% if option_value.price %} {{ option_value.price_prefix }} {{ option_value.price }} {% endif %}" class="img-thumbnail" /> {% endif %}
        {{ option_value.name }}
        {% if option_value.price %}
        ({{ option_value.price_prefix }}{{ option_value.price }})
        {% endif %} </label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %} </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if option.type == 'text' %}
<div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <input type="text" name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}]" value="{{ option.value }}" placeholder="{{ option.name }}" id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}" class="form-control" />
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if option.type == 'textarea' %}
<div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <textarea name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}]" rows="5" placeholder="{{ option.name }}" id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}" class="form-control">{{ option.value }}</textarea>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if option.type == 'file' %}
<div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
  <label class="control-label">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <button type="button" id="button-upload{{ option.product_option_id }}" data-loading-text="{{ text_loading }}" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> {{ button_upload }}</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}]" value="" id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}" />
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if option.type == 'date' %}
<div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}]" value="{{ option.value }}" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
    </span></div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if option.type == 'datetime' %}
<div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <div class="input-group datetime">
    <input type="text" name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}]" value="{{ option.value }}" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
    </span></div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if option.type == 'time' %}
<div class="form-group{% if option.required %} required {% endif %}">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <div class="input-group time">
    <input type="text" name="option[{{ option.product_option_id }}]" value="{{ option.value }}" data-date-format="HH:mm" id="input-option{{ option.product_option_id }}" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
    </span></div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Then clear your `ocmod`, `vqmod` and `twig` caches and check it.

Comment: that worked for me, but by changing options the rate of the product should also update. Some ajax mechanism needs to be implemented in OnChange event of the option

Comment: Yes, this is for displaying options, for updating product price after selecting any options and for add to cart button you need extra codes.

Comment: What may be the reason that this method does not work for the module: featured ?

Comment: When I check through: `echo '<pre>'; print_r ($ data ['products']); echo '</pre>'` result: `[options] => Array( )`

Comment: I don't understand what is the reason for this empty array

Comment: Instead of `$result['product_id']` try `$product_info['product_id']`